# Orthogonality and linear independence about polynomial vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How to prove that polynomial vectors $\left \{ 1,x^{1},x^{2},...,x^{n} \right \}$ are linear independent, but not orthogonal?

Comment: What does the phrase "polynomial vector space is linear independence" mean?

Comment: @T. Bongers Sorry, I edited my question.

Comment: What is the inner product you're considering? If it's the integral of the product over $[0,1]$, you can just calculate that it isn't $0$.

Comment: This really depends on the inner product. If we define $\langle p,q \rangle = \sum_k p_k q_k$ (where $p(t) = \sum_k p_k t^k$, and similarly for $q$), then the above are orthogonal. (Independence is trivial with this inner product.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Bryan's guess about the inner product was correct, then$$\begin{align}\langle x^m\rangle\cdot\langle x^n\rangle&=\int_0^1 x^mx^n\,dx \\ &=\int_0^1x^{m+n}\,dx \\ &=\frac{1}{m+n+1}\ne 0\end{align}$$

As to linear independence, the equation $$c_0\langle x^0\rangle+\cdots+c_n\langle x^n\rangle\equiv \langle \mathbf{0}\rangle$$ is equivalent to $$c_0+c_1x+\cdots +c_nx^n\equiv 0$$ which implies $$c_0=\cdots=c_n=0$$ by standard properties of polynomials.

Comment: I have used brackets to represent vectors, not to denote inner products (for which I use a dot) - hopefully there is no confusion.